# How can I get initial data in CreateView, Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I use Django class-based views. And I have two classes: one for displaying form in the page, and second for handling it:

views.py:

```
class CommentFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = AddCommentForm
    model = Comment
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = ????
        return super(CommentFormView, self).form_valid(form)


class BlogFullPostView(BlogBaseView, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'full_post.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_id'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogFullPostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = AddCommentForm(initial={'post': self.object})
        return context
```

full_post.html:

```
<form action="/addcomment/" method="post" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <button type="submit" >Add comment</button>               
</form>
```

urls:

```
url(r'^blog/post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', BlogFullPostView.as_view()),
url(r'^addcomment/$', CommentFormView.as_view()),
```

And in `def form_valid` I need to fill field post, which value I have passed in `BlogFullPostView` in `get_context_data`: `initial={'post': self.object}`

But how can I get it in CommentFormView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it in this way: Firstly, I try to use `get_initial` method. But I it does  not return anything. So, I decide to hide auto filled field `post` - I make it as hidden field. So, then CreateView easily can create Comment object:

```
widgets = {
            'content': forms.Textarea(),
            'post': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```